Data posting in table is delayed in spring so jsp page is not showing updated data
In our project, we've integrated both Spring-Angular and Servlet-JSP technologies. One of the features is the contact management system. The view page is rendered using JSP-servlet, while the add/edit functionalities have been migrated to Spring-Angular. When a contact is added, edited, or deleted through the Angular page, upon successful completion, the backend redirects to the view all page (JSP).
However, there's an intermittent issue where after adding or deleting a contact and being redirected to the JSP page, the changes aren't immediately reflected. This inconsistency doesn't occur every time; it might happen after deleting a couple of contacts. Interestingly, refreshing the page multiple times eventually displays the expected result. I've thoroughly debugged the code, and with every DB call made, it seems there's no apparent browser cache issue.
We have attempted to address this issue by addding multiple ways to manupulate with DB. We are using hibernate in spring backend, so we have tried hibernate delete, native delete query, criteria builder delete query but nothing solved the issue.
We have also tried adding 4sec timeout in frontend before redirecting after succesful api response.
We verified the deletion of the same contact through an API by retrieving it outside the transactional service to confirm its removal. Despite consistently obtaining the expected result during this process though the "view all" jsp page gives unexpected result.
We also have manipulated with code to find any issue, but found none.
It will be very helpful if someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
